# The best way to get UNC path from local path

Tags: powershell, unc

I have the path like `C:\Program Files\SomeApp`, this path resides on the remote host, e.g. `\\host1`. I'd just like to replace a drive letter with an admin share, e.g. `C:\` → `C$` and add to this path a UNC prefix with a host name and get, eventually, the result like this: `\\host1\C$\Program Files\SomeApp`. A drive letter can have any value, so we can't hardcode it.

I have done it the following way:

```
$dir = "C:\Program Files\SomeApp"
$hostIp = "10.1.1.1"

$dir -replace '.:',"\\$hostIP\$($(Split-Path -Qualifier $dir).TrimEnd(':'))$"
```

However, it looks a bit unclear. Please, propose a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace drive letter and colon at the beginning of the string with the host part and the drive letter followed by a `$`. The rest of the path will remain unchanged.

```psh
$dir -replace '^(.):', "\\$hostIp\`$1$"
```

Escaping the `$` in `$1` prevents PowerShell from trying to expand the reference to the capturing group as a variable.